# Training a Neuronal Network which recognize music chord and intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

In school we have to listen to intervals and chords and determine their name. I'm really into neuronal network. Thats why I want to create a neuronal network with Python which listen to the audio and give me the name as an output. I've learned once that for music I need a LSTM. Should I need for this purpose also a LSTM and how/where should I start? Can anybody teach me how to achieve my goal?

Comment: So first of: This is actually a task which should be decently solveable without any neural networks. But I guess the point here is to use it as an exercise. When solving such a task "traditionally" the obvious approach is to work in frequency space by first transforming the signal with the Fourier Transformation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). Im very confident that is probably also the ideal representation for an ANN for this task. As such I would simply use vectors in frequency space as input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. Yes, you're right it's just for self education purpose.

Comment: @BrunoEigenmann I'm also working on this topic if you wanted to collaborate contact me mwaseemrandhawa@gmail.com. I'm currently phd student at School of Advanced Studies Sant'Anna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need to exactly define the task you like to solve: Do you like to **classify a whole piece of music/track** or do you like to **classify segments of the piece/track**? This will influence which architecture you need to use to solve your task. I will briefly present an approach for each of those tasks.

- **Classifying a track**: Recordings of music are time series, for each of your recordings you need to have a label. Your first intuition of using LSTMs (or RNNs in general) is a good one. Just use your recording transformed into a vector as input-sequence for your LSTM-network and let it put out probabilities for each class. As already indicated by a comment, working in frequency-space can be beneficial. However just using the Fourier-Transformation of the whole track will most likely lose important information since the temporal frequency information is lost. Rather use Short-time Fourier-Transormation ([STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform)) or Mel-frequency cepstrum coefficients ([MFCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum), here is a python-library to calculate them: [libROSA](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/)). Very oversimplified, those methods will transform your time series into some kind of 'image', an two-dimensional frequncy-spectrum, and for image classification task Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) are the way to go.
- **Classifying segments:** If you like to classify segments of your track you need to have a labels for each time-frame in your song. Lets say your song is 3 minutes long and you have a sampling frequency of 60 Hz, your vector representation of the song will have 3*60*60 = 10800 time-frames, thus for each of the entries you need to provide a class label (chord or whatever). Again you can use LSTMs, use your vector as input-sequence and let your network produce an output sequence of the same length of your song and compare it to the class labels. You also could use the previously mentioned STFT- or MFC-coefficients as inputs and take advantage of the frequency information, now you will have a spectrum for each time-frame as input.

I hope these broad ideas will bring you one step closer to solve your task. For implementation details I like to point you to the [keras](https://keras.io/) documentation and to countless tutorials on the internet.

**Disclaimer:**

My knowledge of music theory is rather limited, so please take my answer with a grain of salt and feel free to correct me or ask for clarification. Have fun

Comment: Thanks a lot you. I'm definitely one step further now. Tomorrow I'll check it out in details. Maybe I'll come up with some question then, but at the moment It's clear so far.